# How to connect aws load balance (ELB) to node port 8081

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have 2 EC2 instance where my node app running on 8081 port

```
webserver 1 

http://ec2-3-17-133-60.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/
```

and

```
webserver 2

http://ec2-3-14-71-215.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/
```

Now I am trying to connect it from load balancer

> My configured for this load balancer:

```
Load Balancer Protocol -> HTTP

Load Balancer Port -> 80

Instance Protocol -> HTTP

Instance Port -> 8081

Cipher -> N/A

SSL Certificate -> N/A
```

but when I try to open my elb url

```
http://myfirstelb-1516157627.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/
```

Nothing happens and ended with

> internal error - server connection terminated

What is i am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

The first step to verify is to check the target group of your Load Balancer. Go to the target group and verify targets and health checks.

[image]

Here you will see the status if it's not healthy then Backend not responding to LB,

One reason, Security group not allowing traffic from the port `8081` .

Another reason the ping path does not exist

> Create a target page for the health check and specify its path as the
>   ping path.

[image]

This ping should return `200`

**The connection times out**

> First, verify that you can connect to the target directly from within
>   the network using the private IP address of the target and the health
>   check protocol. If you can't connect, check whether the instance is
>   over-utilized, and add more targets to your target group if it is too
>   busy to respond. If you can connect, it is possible that the target
>   page is not responding before the health check timeout period. Choose
>   a simpler target page for the health check or adjust the health check
>   settings.

**The target did not return a successful response code**

> By default, the success code is 200, but you can optionally specify
>   additional success codes when you configure health checks. Confirm the
>   success codes that the load balancer is expecting and that your
>   application is configured to return these codes on success.

**Your Internet-facing load balancer is attached to a private subnet**

> Verify that you specified public subnets for your load balancer. A
>   public subnet has a route to the Internet Gateway for your virtual
>   private cloud (VPC).

**A security group or network ACL does not allow traffic**

> The security group for the load balancer and any network ACLs for the
>   load balancer subnets must allow inbound traffic from the clients and
>   outbound traffic to the clients on the listener ports.

Here is the what you can get from AWS documentation

**HTTP 500: Internal Server Error
Possible causes:**

> You configured an AWS WAF web access control list (web ACL) and there
>   was an error executing the web ACL rules.
>
> You configured a listener rule to authenticate users, but one of the
>   following is true:

- > The load balancer is unable to communicate with the IdP token endpoint
  >   or the IdP user info endpoint. Verify that the security groups for
  >   your load balancer and the network ACLs for your VPC allow outbound
  >   access to these endpoints. Verify that your VPC has internet access.
  >   If you have an internal-facing load balancer, use a NAT gateway to
  >   enable internet access.
- > The size of the claims returned by the IdP exceeded the maximum size
  >   supported by the load balancer.
- > A client submitted an HTTP/1.0 request without a host header, and the
  >   load balancer was unable to generate a redirect URL.
- > A client submitted a request without an HTTP protocol, and the load
  >   balancer was unable to generate a redirect URL.
- > The requested scope doesn't return an ID token.

[AWS LB http-500-issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-500-issues)